# git push to github via cron on mac

Tags: macos, bash, git, cron, github

I'm trying to use `git push` in a bash script being run by crontab to push a commit to github. At the end of the script I'm doing this:

```
# script processes some files, then:
git add -A
git commit -a -m "Updated $(date)"
git push origin master
```

The add and commit work fine (and the push works fine when running the script from the CL, not using cron), but I get errors on the push to github with cron:

```
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
```

I've searched through other threads (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994663/git-push-via-cron), and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/92683/execute-rsync-command-over-ssh-with-an-ssh-agent-via-crontab/92689#92689)), but it doesn't appear to be an issue with SSH (at least I tried passing SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable in the crontab line and that didn't work). Running OSX 10.8.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR: Solved problems with git push via cron by using SSH instead of HTTPS.**

Thanks to the support team at GitHub I was able to solve this.

The first problem was that `git-credential-osxkeychain` was not in my path when the cron job ran. For me, `git` and `git-credential-osxkeychain` were both being run out of the Xcode command line tools directory:

```
$ which git
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
$ which git-credential-osxkeychain
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
```

When running `which git` from cron, turns out cron was running `git` from `/usr/bin`.

I added the appropriate directory to my `PATH` at the top of the cron job with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

That solved the `git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command` error, but I got yet another error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
```

At the suggestion of the GitHub support team, I solved the problem (without the need for `git-credential-osxkeychain` at all) by authenticating via SSH instead of https:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Comment: Thanks! Same thing worked for me with bitbucket.